Get exact line numbers of changed lines after a branch with some missing commits is merged
So let's say a particular file in the main branch has the following contents:
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            sum += i;
        }
    }
}

Now I fork out a feature branch from main, add few changes and raise a PR to merge it to main. Adding the diff of the change.
diff --git a/Test.java b/Test.java
index fb3a6d4..5379684 100644
--- a/Test.java
+++ b/Test.java
@@ -5,6 +5,7 @@ public class Test {
         for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
         {
             sum += i;
+            log.info("Sum: {}", sum);
         }
     }
 }

Now, before I commit my feature branch to the main, someone else adds another commit on the main branch that affects the same file. So the contents of the file on main branch is now:
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        log.info("Calculating sum");        // This is the new line added to main by someone else
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            sum += i;
        }
    }
}

In my github PR diff, it will show that line number 8 is added in this PR (refer to the git diff shared above). But I'm interested in knowing what would be the line number of this change when it's merged to master, which would be 9 in this case as other person's commit added a new line above my change.
Use case:
I'm working with a tool that provides code analysis on a PR but the issue it reports on a specific line contains the line number after the merge is performed on the base branch (line no. 9 in our example).
I want to post this specific line issues as a comment on a github PR, but it fails as it expects the line number of the change before the merge is performed (line no. 8 in our example).
Note, just for the sake of simplicity I've added a one line change example. In practical use cases, the number of lines changed can be huge.
I couldn't think of any solution apart from pulling in the latest changes from main into my feature branch, but this is not possible to do in my use case. Is there a way to map the line numbers from merging with the latest main, to the line numbers with merging against an older version of main
I'm writing this in python and using unidiff to parse git diffs and make sense out of it.
Update:
I already have the following approach in mind:

Take out a local checkout of the repository.
For every changed file in my branch, append the line number to it at the start/end of the line.
Locally perform the squash and merge to main branch.
Parse the diff of the commit due to this merge operation. Now the lines from the diff can be mapped to the old lines which are encoded at the start/end of the line content.

But this looks more like a naive way of doing things. Looking for some better way to solve this issue. Also, I'm not sure how this would work in case of PRs raised with branch from repo forks.

If you want the analysis tool line numbers to match up with the PR, then they probably should use the same merge. I think this means either 1.) You update your branch to use the same commit tip of main that the tool uses, or 2.) You update the tool to run against the temporary merge commit from the PR instead of the latest main. Depending on how out of date your PR source branches are, #1 is probably slightly more accurate, but #2 is probably simpler.

Side note- I'm not sure if this is what you meant to ask, "Is there some other way to figure out the exact line numbers of the changes after the PR would be merged to main branch?" Isn't that already what the tool is doing for you? Maybe you meant to ask, "Is there a way to map the line numbers from merging with the latest main,  to the line numbers with merging against an older version of main?

Unfortunately, I cannot enforce the branch to use the same commit tip of main, nor can I update the tool to provide analysis based on my branch instead of running on the merge commit.

Yes, I meant to ask the latter. Updating the question.

Why this question is tagged with 'python'?

@Ze'evBen-Tsvi I'm building this utility in python. Refer to the last line of the question.

On further thought, I think the timing of what happens on main after the PR is created isn't relevant. The problem is simply that the merge commit at the time the PR is created has a later version of main than the merge-base of the source branch. This doesn't answer your question, but you said you can't update the source branch after the PR is created, but as a workaround the developer could update it before creating the PR, and then the tool's base and the PR's base would be the same. (And possibly devs would need to update again with every additional push, if the tool runs again.)

"but it fails"—huh? Posting a comment fails because a number in it is "wrong"? what exactly are you talking about here?

I want to post the review comments on a specific line. If a particular line is not part of the diff(due to the merge resulting into changed line nos) then posting the comment fails.

I think "mapping the lines from the merge to the commit before the merge" mainly boils down to: inspect git diff <merge_commit> <merge_commit>^2 -- compare the content of the merge commit to the content of its second parent. Is that a step in the right direction ?

@LeGEC, yes that's correct.

You may inspect the diff (plain regular diff) between the code your analyzer runs on -- if I understood correctly: master, after having merged the branch -- and the code you want to annotate -- the code on the branch before merging.
This convoluted sentence to say: check git diff <merge_commit> <merge_commit>^2 (or git diff master my_branch_before_merge)
That diff will tell you how to shift line indexes to map them to the branch's code.

That does not give the correct line numbers. Specifically, the line numbers it includes are exactly the same as the line numbers shown in the git diff of master_before_merge and feature_branch (as per the example in question, it shows line number 8)

This idea I had in mind with that diff: you should use a tool to scan the diff and tell you "oh, line 9 in master is actually line 8 in my_branch". Does one of the tools you use have this in its features ?

Taking your example: the diff should inidicate a chunk @@ -5,7 +5,6 ... where log.info("Sum: {}", sum); should appear as a context line after the line mentioned as deleted: - log.info("Calculating sum");. You can use this to say "line 9 should be shifted to line 8". Is that what you need ?

actually, if you don't want to deal with context lines, you can use git diff -U0 ; you will still have to handle the lines that appear as actually removed or added.

For large changes, it's not guaranteed the required lines would be always present in the hunk as contextual lines. Also, I did not really understand how can I use this diff to answer the question of "line 9 in the merge commit maps to line 8 in the HEAD of feature branch".

@JavaLearner: I will try to give some explanations if I have more time; in the meantime you can do the following: a. run git diff -U0 <merge_commit> <merge_commit>^2 b. look at the "hunks" that show up, and at the line numbers they indicate: @@ -orig,oldcount +tgt,newcount c. using the info you see in b., can you imagine a way to compute the "mapped line" of a line number located after orig+oldcount ?
